# FactoryGirl: generate a bundle of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, sequence, factory-bot, has-many

Having the next factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    bundle
    number 4567
  end

  factory :bundle do
    start_number 12345
    cards_amount 10
    after_create { |bundle| Factory(:card, :number => start_number, :bundle => bundle) }
  end
end
```

So, each bundle has some cards, f.i. bundle 2-5 has cards 2, 3, 4, 5, start_number = 2 and cards_amount = 4

I want to generate a bundle with 10 cards `Factory(:bundle, :cards_amount => 10)`, but the numbers are the same and don't fill the desired range.

How can I make a bundle with correct card numbers?